# how to send log file using rsyslog

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, rsyslog

I am using Centos 7.6 and have configured rsyslog server and able to send logs(syslog) from client to server, but I need to transfer the file /var/log/wtmp to rsyslog server and I have tried below configuration configuration but not working at all.

[server]

```
$template RemoteLogs,"/var/log/clients/%HOSTNAME%/%$NOW%.log"
*.* ?RemoteLogs
& ~
```

I have tried the below configuration but it is not transferring the file, Please help what is missing

[client]

```
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10") #needs to be done just once

# File 1
input(type="imfile"
      File="/var/log/wtmp"
      Tag="file:wtmp"
#      StateFile="statefile1"
      Severity="info")
```

**Not working**

Comment: wtmp is not a syslog file.

Comment: wtmp seems to be a dump file rather than a log file. Consider using rsync to send it over. Setting up rsyncd on the remote server is very easy too if you don't want to use SSH.

Comment: @MichaelHampton would not it possible to send the wtmp file using rsyslog? rsysnc i will surely consider but is it possible to send via rsyslog?

Comment: It's a binary file, not a text file. So that is not something that rsyslog can do.

Comment: I have tried to configure /var/log/secure to send it via rsyslog and restart the service and getting an error

Comment: Jul  5 21:05:42 node1 rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.conf, on or before line 103: invalid character '0' in object definition - is there an invalid escape sequence somewhere? [v8.24.0-38.el7 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
Jul  5 21:05:42 node1 rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.conf, on or before line 103: syntax error on token ')' [v8.24.0-38.el7 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
Jul  5 21:05:42 node1 rsyslogd: CONFIG ERROR: could not interpret master config file '/etc/rsyslog.conf'. [v8.24.0-38.el7 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]

Comment: input(type="imfile"
      File="/var/log/secure"
      Tag="secure:"
      StateFile="imfile-secure.state"
      Severity="notice"
      Facility="local2"
      reopenOnTruncate="on"
      PersistStateInterval=4000)
      local2.notice           @@192.168.1.34:514